# SQL Finding Duplicates with multiple criteria but different ID numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I work with claims and I have been trying to write a query that captures different claim numbers with multiple criteria, however, I can not get the desired return. The picture I attached is some what an idea of a table I am working with. I need to return different claim numbers with the following criteria being the same:

Sum(billed), Diagnosis_code, Rev_code,  Cpt_Code,   POS_Code, Member_ID, Provider_ID, Organization_ID, DOS, Rendering_Provider_ID.

Those criteria need to match exactly and the may not follow the same ascending or descending order as shown in the table.  Here is the screen shot [image: Table Set Up and Desired Return]

I only want claim_no 101 and 102 to return because they have different claim numbers but match everything else. I do not want claim_no 103 because it does not match all of the above criteria.

I work with SQL Server 2012. Don't know if it maters but DOS data type is datetime. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want rows that match another row, you can do something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.claim_no <> t.claim_no and
                    t2.Diagnosis_code = t.Diagnosis_code and
                    t2.Rev_code = t.Rev_code and
                    . . .
             );
```

Fill in the `. . .` with the conditions that you want.

Comment: Would it be possible to give brief explanation of how this works?

Comment: This returns rows where all the columns with the equality conditions match and the claim numbers are different.

Answer (score 0):

As per your sample data, below query will be work. If you want to add filter condition you can append with this query.

```
Select Clime_no, Sum(billed), Member_ID, Provider_ID, Organization_ID, DOS, Rendering_Provider_ID 
from table_name 
group by Clime_no, Member_ID, Provider_ID, Organization_ID, DOS, Rendering_Provider_ID
```